# How to convert '__NSIArrayI' to JSON Array in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsarray, alamofire

I am new to `Swift 4` and working on an `iOS app`. I have the following `JSON` data retrieved from the `server` which will be extracted to `data table`.

```
[
  {
    "fund_nav_validity":"24 August to 31 August 2016\n",
    "fund_nav_cost":10,
    "fund_nav_sell":9.85,
    "nav_id":118,
    "fund_nav_buy":10,
    "fund_id":1,
    "nav_as_on_date":"24-Aug-16",
    "fund_nav_market":9.95
  },
  {
    "fund_nav_validity":"04 September to 07 September 2016\n",
    "fund_nav_cost":10,
    "fund_nav_sell":9.85,
    "nav_id":117,
    "fund_nav_buy":10,
    "fund_id":1,
    "nav_as_on_date":"01-Sep-16",
    "fund_nav_market":9.95
 }
]
```

I have done following task in the navdata function to retrieve the '__NSIArrayI' to JSON:

```
func getNAVData(){
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post).responseJSON{
            response in
            if response.result.isSuccess{
                print("Success")
                //let navDataJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!
                let navDataJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)

                print(navDataJSON)
            }else{
                print("Failed")
            }
        }

    }
```

I need to convert it to `JSON Array` which is done in `java`. How to do the similar task in `Swift 4`?

Comment: show your tried code.

Comment: I have added the code. Basically, I did not try to convert it to JSON Array as I do not know the correct way to do this.

Comment: add some additioal code

Comment: Isn't this the json array?

Comment: Yes. It is JSON Array?

Comment: You should look into using `Codable` when decoding json in swift, there are plenty of similar question here to look at and many tutorials and articles elsewhere online. So do some research first and come back if you get stuck. Here is a article from Apple, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types to get you started,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are in the right way, in here you need to convert your  JSON response to array the reason your json started with this type[{}] and check your JSON response contains the value or not in intially. try the below code

```
 if response.result.isSuccess{
            print("Success")
            // convert your JSON to swiftyJSON array type if your JSON response as array as well as check its contains data or not
             guard let resJson = JSON(responseObject.result.value!).array ,  !resJson.isEmpty else { return
            }
            // create the Swifty JSON array for global access like wise
            var navDataJSON  =  [JSON]() //[JSON]() --> Swifty-JSON array memory allocation.
            navDataJSON =  resJson


        }
```

Comment: reason for downvote,with out reason dont give the downvote, if its valid I ready to update the answer]

Comment: No explanation of what the code does and how it helps OP, I think we should expect much better from someone with a 67k+ reputation. And why use something like swiftyjson when the built in support for decoding json is so good in swift.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - appreciate , I update the answer please check, in here we can suggest to use codeable but we cant force to use, based on the developer  preference it will vary

Comment: The solution provided by @Anbu.Karthik worked. Thank you for adding the explanation in the code as well.

Comment: OP is, as stated, new to swift so it's a pity that the solution in accepted answer is built on a 3rd party library that is not the preferred solution by the swift community but I guess it is the way that it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use SwiftyJSON return `responseData` rather than `responseJSON`. This avoids a double conversion, and handle always a potential error

```
func getNAVData(){
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post).responseData { response in

        switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):
                 let navDataJSON = JSON(data).arrayValue
                 print(navDataJSON)                 

             case .failure(let error): print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

The result `navDataJSON` is a JSON array.

---

However in Swift 4+ it's highly recommended to use the more efficient and built-in `Codable` protocol

```
struct Fund : Decodable {
    let fundNavValidity, navAsOnDate : String
    let fundNavCost, navId, fundNavBuy, fundId : Int
    let fundNavSell, fundNavMarket : Double
}

func getNAVData(){
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post).responseData { response in

        switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):
                 do {
                     let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                     decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                     let navDataJSON = decoder.decode([Fund].self, from : data)
                     print(navDataJSON)
                 } catch { print(error) }                 

             case .failure(let error): print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

The result is an array of `Fund` structs.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the JSON array and if you want to convert to model Array then you can use create Model Struct and confirm to Decodable Protocol, without using SwiftyJSON using inbuilt solution to parse JSON.

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Element
struct Model: Decodable {
    let fundNavValidity: String
    let fundNavCost: Int
    let fundNavSell: Double
    let navId: Int
    let fundNavBuy: Int
    let fundId: Int
    let navAsOnDate: String
    let fundNavMarket: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case fundNavValidity = "fund_nav_validity"
        case fundNavCost = "fund_nav_cost"
        case fundNavSell = "fund_nav_sell"
        case navId = "nav_id"
        case fundNavBuy = "fund_nav_buy"
        case fundId = "fund_id"
        case navAsOnDate = "nav_as_on_date"
        case fundNavMarket = "fund_nav_market"
    }
}
```

then in getNAVData method you can use JSONDecoder to covert to Model struct array like below

```
func getNAVData() {
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post).responseJSON {
            response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):
                do {
                    let modelArray = try JSONDecoder().decode([Model].self, from: data)
                    print(modelArray)
                } catch {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```